# Androidstudio Installed App from APK appears twice on phone

Tags: java, android

Whenever I install my App, wether via Androidstudio or via APK, it is shown twice on my phone. What causes this? I suppose this won't happen anymore when its  installed via Play Store?

NOW I HAVE TO ADD MORE TEXT BECAUSE WTF STACKOVERFLOW.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.zawarudo">

    <application
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/thatched"
        android:label="Norse Expansion"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:resumeWhilePausing="true"

            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".GameActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:resumeWhilePausing="true"

            tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>




    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Share your AndroidManifest.xml file code

Comment: I updated my post.

Comment: you added two launcher activity remove one launcher activity its work perfectly or make default activity one of them

Answer (score 1):

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

This segment of xml can only appear once in your whole application. Make sure you don't have another "conflicting" manifest (.aar, Unity embedded application, etc.) that also has this. If it has, discard it.

Source that helped me when I had the same issue : https://answers.unity.com/questions/1362683/unity-apk-installing-2-icons.html

Answer (score 1):

You have defined two activities as your launcher in your manifest file change one of them from

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

To

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
```